# ImmutableJS - Updating a cell of a matrix

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have this matrix:

```
const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({ 
  board: [
          ['','',''],
          ['','',''],
          ['','','']
         ]
});
```

And this function:

```
function cellClick(state,i,j) { 

const board = state.get('board');
var newBoard = board.map(function(arr) {
    return arr.slice();
  });  
newBoard.set(i,j,'Hi');
alert(newBoard.get(i).get(j));
}
```

1. Clones the matrix (to newBoard obj)
2. Try to set a value for a matrix cell - Doesn't work
3. Tries to output a message with the cell values - Doesn't work

I've tried to read ImmutableJS docs but couldn't find anything talking about setting a value inside a matrix ("List" type of ImmutableJS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `.setIn([i, j], 'Hi')` *but* it will not mutate the value. That's the point of ImmutableJS. It will return a slightly changed version of your original data structure. If you just write `setIn` on a line and don't assign the result anywhere then nothing will happen. Nothing will change. That's the point.

`getIn` and `setIn` are very useful. They can also provide default values if something doesn't exist. I also don't think you need `.slice()` there. You don't need to clone anything at all.

It's an immutable data structure, nobody can change it, that's the beautiful part.

```
const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({ 
  board: [
          ['','',''],
          ['','',''],
          ['','','']
         ]
});

const nextState = initialState.setIn(['board', 0, 0], 'Hi')

// Now nextState has 'Hi' in it's first column and row.
// initialState is still the same as it was, it is not changed.
```

Comment: so actually I can do this instead ? :
board.setIn([i,j],'Hi');
alert(board.getIn([i,j]));

Comment: No, you can not. You must assign the result of the `setIn` call somewhere, it is immutable, it does not mutate board, it returns a **new** board with your change applied. You will also need to call `.toJS()` on the data if you wish to log or alert it anywhere.

Comment: I would highly recommend reading everything on the ImmutableJS homepage first https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/